multiplicity-adjustment w/ unequal variance & pre-planned vs post hoc
The (only) answer to this question says

If the variability of the data in each category of your factor is
non-constant, that would invalidate ... your multiplicity-adjusted
post-hoc p-values.

Why couldn't Welch's test, which allows for unequal variances, be used in conjunction with a false discovery rate controlling procedure or a family-wise error rate controlling procedure?
That answer also says

Whether or not you would bother with the global ANOVA p-value
therefore depends on whether or not your multiple comparisons were
pre-planned. If they were, you could ignore the global ANOVA p-value.
If they were not, you couldn't. The age of computers has nothing to do
with it, really.

Why does it matter if the multiple comparisons were pre-planned? Why couldn't one just pre-plan to compare them all (with a computer)?
(FWIW, I wanted this to be a comment to the quoted answer, but don't have sufficient reputation.)

I can only provide an opinion on the original answer:
The first point has nothing to do with multiple testing, rather with the homogeneity of variance assumption that ANOVA makes. It's probably quite strong to say this 'invalidates' it, but you will lose efficiency for sure.
The second point is a nuance in the original question: they ask whether they can still do pairwise comparisons after observing the global F-test while only correcting the latter for multiplicity. If you want to maintain FWER you also have to address this sequence: you cannot make the decision to use either the F-test or the pairwise comparisons after having observed the data. Doing so will (likely mildly) inflate type I assertion rate if you don't correct for the multiplicity between the F-test and the pairwise ones, although usually their correlation will be very high & the F-test is the more powerful one, especially versus Bonferroni.
If you specify upfront that you only consider one of those tests that's a valid way of handling multiplicity without having to correct for the other, even if your software spits out the other P-value(s) by default as well.

Thanks. Doesn't "multiplicity-adjusted post-hoc p-values" mean the first quote isn't referring to ANOVA assumptions?

In addition the full quote says "...invalidate both your global ANOVA p-value and your multiplicity-adjusted post-hoc p-values", which again seems to indicate that the multiple testing is invalid (or less efficient, as you put it). Am I missing something?

The standard t-test makes the same assumption, and the multiplicity adjustment is a function of the unadjusted values.

What about Welch's t-test though? That allows for different variances, right? Couldn't that be used with a false discovery rate controlling procedure or a family-wise error rate controlling procedure?

Yes, of course it could, just like the regular t-test. The Welch correction relaxes the equal variances assumption somewhat & many software packages, including R, use it by default.
